# Silverlight MouseMove inconsistency for Chrome vs FF/IE

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome, mousemove

I've got a listbox with images. I'm capturing MouseMove. In FF (Win7 & OSX) & also in IE8, this fires whenever the mouse is moved over the images. In Chrome (on OSX), however, it only fires while the mouse button is pressed down. This Chrome behaviour would actually be quite useful, but only if I could control it, rather than have it just randomly happen on certain browsers. So does anyone know if there's some overall setting somewhere that's making it behave this way in Chrome, or is it just an inconsistency in SL implementations?
I suspect the latter, since I've never been able to find a way in SL of testing whether the mouse button is down.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: by the way, Chrome isn't supported properly until Silverlight 4.0

Comment: If you are only wanting to check when the mouse is down, just set a flag on the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event and unset it on the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event and if the flag is not set ignore the `MouseMove` event.

Comment: Ray: It's SL 4.
Stephan: I've found that solution doesn't work too well. Problem is when you've got lots of UIElements masking each other's mouse events, and you also have to worry about the mouse leaving the area etc, it gets very hacky and fragile.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the problem is MouseMove, MouseEnter and MouseLeave events are not fired when mouse left button is down.

I had the same problem with TextBox. Actually it happened in IE too and my googling told me it is so by design. Further googling revealed the reason: the element is capturing mouse using **CaptureMouse()** method. So I have just derived from TextBox and overrode **OnMouseMove(...)** method:

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseMove(e);
    ReleaseMouseCapture();
}
```

Note: I'm not sure, whether capturing mouse is the only thing the base implementation of this method does, so I added **ReleaseMouseCapture()** after calling it, but commenting it out also works, of course.